# React Native Video Processing Videoplayer not showing

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm implementing React-Native-Video-Processing into my code.
Once I test my code, I can't see Videoplayer in Screen.
Only audio was playing without Video.
I'm not sure why it's not showing Videoplayer.

"react": "16.6.3",
"react-native": "0.58.5",
"react-native-video-processing": "^1.20.0"

Here's my code

```
<View style={{flex: 1}} onLayout={this.onLayout} >
     <VideoPlayer
         ref={ref => this.videoPlayerRef = ref}
         play={true}     // default false
         replay={true}   // should player play video again if it's ended
         rotate={true}   // use this prop to rotate video if it captured in landscape mode iOS only
         source={this.props.url}
         playerWidth={width} // iOS only
         playerHeight={height} // iOS only
         style={styles.backgroundColor}
         bbackground_Color={'black'}
         onChange={({ nativeEvent }) => console.log({ nativeEvent })} // get Current time on every second
     />
 </View>
```

I've tested my code with Android and I only wish that it's working for Android, not ios.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

please mention width and height for video player to view it.

```
style={{height: Dimensions.get("window").height, width:Dimensions.get("window").width}}
```

or find full code below

```
<VideoPlayer
    ref={ref => this.videoPlayerRef = ref}
    startTime={30}  // seconds
    endTime={120}   // seconds
    play={true}     // default false
    replay={true}   // should player play video again if it's ended
    rotate={true}   // use this prop to rotate video if it captured in landscape mode iOS only
    source={this.state.video.uri}
    playerWidth={300} // iOS only
    playerHeight={500} // iOS only
    style={{ backgro`enter code here`undColor: 'black' }}
    resizeMode={VideoPlayer.Constants.resizeMode.COVER}
    style={{height: Dimensions.get("window").height, width:Dimensions.get("window").width}}
    onChange={({ nativeEvent }) => console.log({ nativeEvent })} // get Current time on every second
/>
```